# Call to undefined function xml_parser_create()

Tags: php, xml, linux, nginx, xml-parsing

Could you please help me in resolving this conflict. I am tryin to run a xml_parse_create.
My server configurations:
[root@server ~]# php -v 
PHP 7.0.22 (cli) (built: Aug  7 2017 16:18:27) ( NTS )

[root@server ~]# nginx -v 
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2

OS: CentOS 7.3.1611 (Core)

Details of my YUM installation:

```
[root@server ~]# yum list installed | grep php
php70u-cli.x86_64                       7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius     
php70u-common.x86_64                    7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius     
php70u-fpm.x86_64                       7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius     
php70u-fpm-nginx.noarch                 7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius     
php70u-mysqlnd.x86_64                   7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius     
php70u-pdo.x86_64                       7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           @ius
```

Here is the details of the investigation:

I tried executing following code in test.php:

```
<?php
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create("");
print $xml_parser;<br>
?>
```

[root@server ~]# php /tmp/test.php 
**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function**

[root@server ~]# sudo yum install php-xml
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirrors.tds.net
 * extras: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
 * ius: ius.mirror.constant.com
 * remi-safe: repo1.ash.innoscale.net
 * updates: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7 for package: php-xml-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-42.el7 will be installed
**--> Processing Conflict: php70u-common-7.0.22-2.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0.22**
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
**Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64**
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: Add the output of `yum list installed | grep php` to your question

Comment: Added in my question. `[root@server ~]# yum list installed | grep php
php70u-cli.x86_64                       7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           ius     
php70u-common.x86_64                    7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           ius     
php70u-fpm.x86_64                       7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           ius     
php70u-fpm-nginx.noarch                 7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           ius     
php70u-mysqlnd.x86_64                   7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           ius     
php70u-pdo.x86_64                       7.0.22-2.ius.centos7           ius `

Comment: Try `yum purge php-xml; yum install -y php70u-xml`

Comment: Thank you Tarun, now it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 12):

Under ubuntu you can do the same as @Tarun pointed

```
apt-get install php-xml
apt-get search php |grep xml
```

Comment: on some versions of ubuntu you will need to use
apt-cache search php | grep xml

Answer (score 8):

You need to remove `php-xml` and use `php70u-xml`

```
yum purge php-xml; yum install -y php70u-xml
```

Many people install php using some tutorial which will enable an external repo. Php gets installed using packages from this external repo. While installing extensions they try and use package names from default repo. So that is what your problem was.

Always first see where your packages are installed from

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

Then always make sure you that you choose the package which belongs to the same repo

```
yum search php | grep xml
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening to you on Laravel using PHP 7.4 on CentOs, this is how you fix it:

1. Make sure you have the libraries installed. For that, get the packages that matches to your PHP version with the following command:

   `yum list php | grep xml`
2. Install the packages that match your PHP version. As shown in the following example:

   `yum install ea-php74-php-xml.x86_64`
3. Register the extensions to your php.ini file as follows:

   ```
   extension=xmlwriter.so
   extension=xml.so
   extension=xmlreader.so
   ```
4. Restart your server

   ```
   `sudo apachectl restart`
   ```
5. Add extensions to the composer.json

   ```
    "ext-simplexml": "*",
    "ext-xml": "*",
    "ext-xmlrpc": "*",
    "ext-xmlwriter": "*",
   ```
6. Update composer

   ```
   `composer update`
   ```

Et voilà!